# How append an asp:chart and asp:image to html?

Tags: c#

how append an asp:chart and an asp:image to html..? I need to create an html file . which should contain an asp:chart and asp:image using C#

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"
           AlternateText="Image text"
           ImageAlign="left"
           ImageUrl="images/image1.jpg"/>
```

Here is nice tutorial for charts
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what i needed, i am trying to create an html file using c#.. i can get the text file in a text like,                                                                      HTML.Append("</td>");
            HTML.Append("<td>" + textBoxName.Text.ToString() + "</td>");
            HTML.Append("</tr>");                                          i need to add an image into it..